# Run python script by shebang with `time` command

Tags: python, bash, time, shebang

I have a python script, which I want to be able to run from bash.
This is simply solved by shebang.
The next step is to implement the time command into the shebang.
My best but not the complete successful idea was to use

```
#!/usr/bin/env -vS bash -c "time /usr/bin/python3 -OO"
```

which does so sadly not make python interpret the script file and ends in an interactive python session.

The output is

```
split -S:  ‘bash -c "time /usr/bin/python3 -OO"’
 into:    ‘bash’
     &    ‘-c’
     &    ‘time /usr/bin/python3 -OO’
executing: bash
   arg[0]= ‘bash’
   arg[1]= ‘-c’
   arg[2]= ‘time /usr/bin/python3 -OO’
   arg[3]= ‘./mypycheck.py’
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12)
```

How can I do the job? Thanks in advance.

Comment: which code have tried please share?

Comment: @AkashPagar: That is independent from the python code of course. The question is simply how to invoke the python interpreter.

Comment: I would recommend either having a bash script used to just run `time python3 /path/to/file.py` or just run `time ./file.py` yourself.
This method will cause you pain when it comes to portability.

Comment: Could you clarify if your question is about timing a python script (through shebang because it seemed feasible)? Or more about how to combine a couple of  commands in a shebang with env's (recent) -S option?

Comment: @Demi-Lune  The major task is having timing transparent integrated in the function. Using `time` from bash has just the granularity of interest. The plan was to have it automatically in every run. It seems that I have the soultion - just trying once again and then I'll publish it here, of course.

Comment: It's interesting to note that the difficulty is actually with `bash -c`, not the shebang: `bash -c echo python3 test.py` displays an empty line. A workaround is (as you did) to quote or backslash the spaces: `bash -c echo\ python3\ test.py` or `bash -c 'echo python3 test.py'`. But none of these ideas can be applied to the shebang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end summing up all helpful details from here, I was able to reach my goal with the following solution.

1. Installing `time` utiliy by running `sudo apt install time`
2. Using the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env -S /usr/bin/time /usr/bin/python3 -OO`

And now all is running the way I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by creating a secondary bash script, and just invoking it as the shebang.

```sh
Kamori@Kamori-PC:/tmp# ./timed.py
hello

real    0m0.028s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.000s
Kamori@Kamori-PC:/tmp# cat timed.py
#!/bin/bash startup.sh

print("hello")
Kamori@Kamori-PC:/tmp# cat startup.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

time python3.7 timed.py
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a good idea but a bit of workaround. I'm looking for a single shebang solution.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with a shebang, because it's format ([on Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)) is:

```
#!interpreter [optional-arg]
```

And this argument is passed as single string (see "Interpreter scripts" and "Interpreter scripts" in the linked document). In other words, you cannot pass multiple arguments (unless they can be concatenated to a single string) to an interpreter. This is down to kernel implementation of how code gets executed.

Using `env -S` is also not helpful here, because as you can see in your debugging output:

```
   arg[0]= ‘bash’
   arg[1]= ‘-c’
   arg[2]= ‘time /usr/bin/python3 -OO’
   arg[3]= ‘./mypycheck.py’
```

It runs shell, tells to run a command (`-c`) starting python wrapped in `time` and then passed `‘./mypycheck.py’` to bash (not python) as its last argument. meaning of which is (applying to the bash):

> `-c`
>
> If  the  `-c` option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument `command_string`.  If there are arguments after the `command_string`, the first argument is assigned to `$0` and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters.  The assignment to `$0` sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning
>    and error messages.

As for you objective. You could create a wrapper that is used as an interpreter in place of `env` in your case that does desired actions and passed the script to an actual interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you already simply tried

```
#!/usr/bin/time python3
```

Was it not ok?
(i.e. is the `-OO` in your tests mandatory?)

Example:

```
$ cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/time python3
import sys
print (sys.argv)

$ ./test.py 
['./test.py']
0.01user 0.00system 0:00.02elapsed 95%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 9560maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1164minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Although this doesn't solve the `-OO` yet

Comment: `time` is not a real command, it is a feature of bash. There is no time command (for me). `which time` returns nothing and reading `man bash` explains something for that.

Comment: There's a time bash builtin (`help time`), and (at least on my debian) also a `/usr/bin/time`

Comment: Sorry, for me (I relied on beeing the same everywere) on LSFW debian `which time` is empty and `man time` shows details on time.h. Indeed `help time` shows how to use. But for me there is no binary.

Comment: `apt-get install time` installs it.